# variable with late modifier not getting initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my provider code for connectivity, where the variable _isOnline will be assigned later.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ConnectivityProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  // this will hold the status
  late bool _isOnline;

  // method to set the initial state and listen
  Future<void> updateStatus() async {
    // getting the object
    Connectivity connectivity = Connectivity();

    // getting the status
    final ConnectivityResult connectivityResult =
        await connectivity.checkConnectivity();

    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      _isOnline = false;
    } else {
      _isOnline = true;
    }
  }

  // getter to get the online status
  bool get isOnline => _isOnline;
}
```

I'm assigning the value to the _isOnline in another page's initState:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // getting the initial status of the connection
    Provider.of<ConnectivityProvider>(context, listen: false).updateStatus();
}
```

But I'm still getting an error saying that the variable was not initialized even though I did assign it in the initState:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `_isOnline` is initialized asynchronously, so any code that tries to use `_isOnline` before the asynchronous call to `connectivity.checkConnectivity()` completes will result in a `LateInitializationError`.  You must use `late` *only* if you can guarantee that the variable will be initialized before it's used.  Otherwise you must initialize it earlier or make it nullable.  In general, `late` should be a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears because somewhere in your codes call the `isOnline` when it is still not initialized. You can just change the variable from `late bool _isOnline;` to `bool _isOnline = false;` to make sure the internet is not connected as default when users open the app.